# Download file using RESTlet API in Android

Tags: android

It will be great if anyone can help me to understand how to use RESTlet API in Android to download any file like image and store it in internal memory.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just grab it out of the payload, once you have called the GET method on the right URL, and typecast the payload to whatever you marshalled it as (byte[] for instance). But for such a simple scenario, why don't you just use Apache HttpClient?